# Kohana htaccess - redirect from www

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, kohana

My Kohana site has a htaccess:

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
 <Files .*>
   Order Deny,Allow
   Deny From All
 </Files>

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

Help to make a redirect from www.site.com to site.com.  How to change this htaccess?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right below `RewriteBase /` add:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```